# Error while trying to decrypt RSA

Tags: java, scala, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Trying to decrypt the below value which is already encrypted using RSA `PrivateKey` I'm using same key pair `publicKey` to decrypt.

```
Encrypted: Mfb5ano1MmrPX0gliGld/h1T6XegLq4P6G52fdr1vCwWlle5K1Y6FSshJ8E495sVjhpC9M10zDzqymkkxSOxbNz5qpLCcQQcfgkTIwALspWr18SyyfuKwO4H6TxpV6+eohgn4n+gt9aos4Tx/l4AKWeI7mpTR5TzzBUMgV3cpfM=

import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.KeyPair
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator
import java.security.PrivateKey
import java.security.PublicKey
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import javax.crypto.Cipher

object AsymmetricCryptography {

  var cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
  var keyGen: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
  var pair: KeyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair()
  var privateKey: PrivateKey = pair.getPrivate()
  var publicKey: PublicKey = pair.getPublic()

def main(args: Array[String]) {

var random: SecureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
this.keyGen.initialize(1024, random)

var plaintext = new Array[Byte](117)
random.nextBytes(plaintext)

this.privateKey = getPrivate("./src/main/resources/privateKeyLicenceGenerator")
this.publicKey = getPublic("./src/main/resources/publicKeyLicenceGenerator")
 val msg: Array[String] = Source.fromFile("encryptedfile").getLines().toArray
val inputs = msg.mkString("").split("<TOKEN>")
val encrypted: String = inputs(1).replaceAll("</TOKEN>", "")
println(encrypted) //encrypted = above mensioned
val decrypted_msg: String = decryptText(encrypted, publicKey)
println(decrypted_msg)
}

def decryptText(msg: String, key: PublicKey): String = {
this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)
val cipher = new String(this.cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(msg)), "UTF-8")
return cipher
}

def getPublic(filename: String): PublicKey = {
val keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath())
val spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
val kf: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
val a = kf.generatePublic(spec)
return a
}
}
```

Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at wordcount.AsymmetricCryptography$.decryptText(AsymmetricCryptography.scala:49)
at wordcount.AsymmetricCryptography$.main(AsymmetricCryptography.scala:43)
at wordcount.AsymmetricCryptography.main(AsymmetricCryptography.scala)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar neither with this lib nor with this language. Though judging by a stack trace and a listing you should look into Base64 decoding part. Try to change encoding. Anyway it's a padding error which means that either pk do not match sk or ct is malformed.

Comment: Yes, I read it from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872614/javax-crypto-badpaddingexception-decryption-error?rq=1

Comment: You hard coded the encrypted text in the above code but generated a new key pair. This cannot work.

Comment: @Henry, Code Updated Actually I'm referring to a PrivateKey after generating a new key pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cipher you are using is probably incorrect. The javax.crypto library does not have all ciphers available, and you may need to use an external library. At this moment there is no way for me to tell which cipher you need to use, or where you can find the correct algorithm. The following might help you to figure that out for yourself.

For example, rsa-oaep works with a digest method and a mask generation function (MGF). If you use the following cipher, which was available on our system, it didn't work:

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
```

We got the same exception that you mentioned.

Inspecting the cipher used for encryption, we discovered that the MGF was incorrect:

```
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#rsa-oaep">
       <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
       <xenc11:MGF xmlns:xenc11="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#mgf1sha256"/>
    </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
```

Notice `mgf1sha256` in the xenc11:MFG tag, which is different from `MGF1Padding`. This function was not available in our system, but it is available in Apache Santuario (http://santuario.apache.org/)